Як правильно чергувати прийменники/сполучники? Й або i? У або в? З або із?
Я хоч і перечитала декілька разів різні джерела, як вживати прийменники, але все одно до кінця не змогла зрозуміти, то ж питаю тут. Я наведу декілька беззмістовних речень для прикладу.

Любисток із янтаря.


Янтаря з любисток.

Я гадаю, що в 1-му реченні повинно бути «із», тому що в транскрипції «я» дає «йа». Тобто, виходить, що «із» ніби-то між приголосними: «к» і «й».
Чи я не права й повинно бути «з»?
У другому реченні в транскрипції «йа» і «л». Тобто, «а» і «л», а «з» ставиться після голосного. А якщо спершу буде приголосний, а потім — голосний? У наступному реченні ставити «з» або «із»?

Журнал з агрусом

На початку речення завжди вживають «з». А після розділових знаків? Чи треба брати до уваги літери до коми?

Кіт ішов, з дивовижною спритністю підстрибнув — і приземлився.

Наприклад, тут «в» і «д» — приголосні. Чи потрібно ставити «із»?
А в лапках?

Цей «з родзинкою».

«З» або «із»?
І що вище стоїть: правило про початок речення, що треба ставити «з», або правило, що треба перед свистячими ставити «із»?

З/із цієї хвилини?


Перед і після (незалежно від положення за новим правописом) я/є/ю/ї/є/й треба ставити «і»?

Борис і Яна. Майя і цивілізація. Ґанна й Борис. Борис й Анатолій.

Щодо розділових знаків?
Яна, ішовши до магазину, натрапила на кота.
«Ішовши» або «йшовши»?
І таке саме питання щодо лапок, як і з «із/з».

«В» ставиться незалежно від положення голосної?
Вулиця в місті. Проспект в Онтаріо.
Після розділових знаків завжди ставимо «у»?
Він, у Анатолія бувши, відремонтував машину.
Буду справді дуже вдячна, якщо скажете, які речення — правильні, а які — ні, і чому Ви так вважаєте.
